# Portable BrainFuck Interpreter in ANSI C89

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, interpreter, brainfuck, c89

I wrote this BrainFuck interpreter in ANSI C89:

```
/*
 *  Copyright © 2019 James Larrowe
 *
 *  This file is part of bf.
 *
 *  bf is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 *  (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *  bf is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *  GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *  along with bf.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEF_MEM_SIZE 32768

#define ezs(x) (x)
#define exit_if_true(x, y) if(x) exit_perr(y)

void bf_interp(unsigned char *, const unsigned char *, size_t, size_t);
void exit_perr(const char *);
unsigned char *read_file(const char *, size_t *);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t file_size,
           mem_size = DEF_MEM_SIZE;
    unsigned char *file, *mem;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incorrect number of arguments\n"
                        "  Usage: %s [file] (args...)\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    file = read_file(argv[1], &file_size);
    mem = calloc(sizeof(*mem), mem_size);
    exit_if_true(mem == NULL, "calloc()");

    bf_interp(mem, file, mem_size, file_size);

    free(mem);
    free(file);

    return 0;
}

void bf_interp(unsigned char *sp, const unsigned char *ip, size_t sp_size, size_t ip_size)
{
    long spc = 0, ipc = 0;

    while(ezs(size_t)ipc < ip_size)
    {
        /* I would put this inside the switch
         * but clang warns about "unreachable code".
         */
        int nest;
        switch(ip[ipc])
        {
            case '>':
            {
                spc++;
                if(ezs(size_t)spc >= sp_size)
                {
                    unsigned char *tmp;

                    tmp = realloc(sp, sp_size + DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                    exit_if_true(tmp == NULL, "realloc()");

                    memset(tmp+sp_size, 0, DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                    memcpy(tmp, sp, sp_size);

                    sp_size += DEF_MEM_SIZE;

                    free(sp);
                    sp = tmp;
                }
                break;
            }
            case '<':
            {
                spc--;
                if(spc < 0)
                {
                    fputs("Error: spc < 0\n", stderr);
                    exit(1);
                }
                break;
            }
            case '+':
            {
                sp[spc]++;
                break;
            }
            case '-':
            {
                sp[spc]--;
                break;
            }
            case '.':
            {
                putchar(sp[spc]);
                break;
            }
            case ',':
            {
                int c = getchar();
                if(c != EOF)
                    sp[spc] = ezs(unsigned char)c;
                break;
            }
            case '[':
            {
                if(sp[spc] == 0)
                {
                    for( nest = 1; nest; )
                    {
                        ipc++;
                        if(ezs(size_t)ipc >= ip_size)
                        {
                            fputs("Error: ipc >= ip_size\n", stderr);
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        nest += (ip[ipc] == '[');
                        nest -= (ip[ipc] == ']');
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case ']':
            {
                if(sp[spc])
                {
                    for( nest = 1; nest; )
                    {
                        ipc--;
                        if(ipc < 0)
                        {
                            fputs("Error: ipc < 0\n", stderr);
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        nest -= (ip[ipc] == '[');
                        nest += (ip[ipc] == ']');
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        ipc++;
    }
}

unsigned char *read_file(const char *argv1, size_t *size)
{
    unsigned char *file;
    size_t was_read, sz;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(argv1, "r");
    exit_if_true(fp == NULL, "fopen()");

    exit_if_true(fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == -1, "fseek()");

    sz = ezs(size_t)ftell(fp);
    exit_if_true(sz == ezs(size_t)-1, "ftell()");

    *size = sz;

    file = malloc(sz);
    exit_if_true(file == NULL, "malloc()");

    exit_if_true(fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) == -1, "fseek()");

    was_read = fread(file, 1, sz, fp);
    if(was_read != sz)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read file.\n"
                        "Read %zu bytes when %zu bytes were expected\n",
                        was_read, sz);
        exit(1);
    }

    exit_if_true(fclose(fp) == EOF, "fclose()");

    return file;
}

void exit_perr(const char *str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}
```

It's been tested and it works properly, but there are some design issues I'm worried about. In particular:

- Have I split the code up into functions enough?
- Do I have variable names that describe the code well?
- How can I make it more efficient around the nesting code (`case '[':` and `case ']':`)?
- Is it portable?
- Are there any issues with it that I may have overlooked?

This runs and produces results identical to many other BrainFuck interpreters that I've tried.

This is available under the GPLv3 in my GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/JL2210/bf).

Comment: Uff, this is horribly complicated code (hard to maintain, hard to find a bug). Keep it simple. Take a look at [this one](https://github.com/xbarin02/bf/blob/master/bf.c) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, what's the deal with `#define ezs(x) (x)`? Is it some kind of trick to either hide C-style casts, or make them more greppable? If the latter, why such a short name? How about `#define CAST_TO(x) (x)`?

---

Other naming comments:

- `was_read` sounds like a boolean. I think you mean `bytes_read` or even `num_bytes_read`.
- Your function names are all tersified according to different conventions. You've got `interpret_brainfuck` (verb-noun), `perror_and_exit` (verb-and-verb), and `read_file` (verb-noun) — but you've tersified them as `bf_interp` (noun-abbrverb), `exit_perr` (reversed the order of the verbs for some reason), and... okay, `read_file` is a good name. :)

---

```
#define exit_if_true(x, y) if(x) exit_perr(y)
```

(A) Why is this not a (`static`) `inline` function? I don't think the macro is buying you anything.

(B) Consider:

```
if (cond1)
    exit_if_true(cond2, "message");
else
    puts("cond1 was false");  // LIES!
```

Always, always, always use proper macro hygiene in C and C++! It costs nothing, and it shows the reader that you know what you're doing, and every so often it avoids a really sneaky bug.
What you should have written was:

```
#define exit_if_true(x, y) do { if (x) exit_perr(y); } while (0)
```

or, even better,

```
static inline void exit_if_true(bool b, const char *message) {
    if (b) {
        exit_perr(message);
    }
}
```

---

```
size_t file_size,
       mem_size = DEF_MEM_SIZE;
unsigned char *file, *mem;
```

Please, for the sake of your readers, write each declaration on its own line. I mean, it costs literally *one* more line of source code to write

```
size_t file_size;
size_t mem_size = DEF_MEM_SIZE;
unsigned char *file;
unsigned char *mem;
```

This also calls attention to the fact that you failed to initialize three of these variables. That smells like a bug. Let's see...

```
file = read_file(argv[1], &file_size);
mem = calloc(sizeof(*mem), mem_size);
```

Ah. So it actually would have *saved* you several lines of code to write simply

```
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incorrect number of arguments\n"
                    "  Usage: %s [file] (args...)\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
}
size_t file_size;
unsigned char *file = read_file(argv[1], &file_size);

size_t mem_size = DEF_MEM_SIZE;
unsigned char *mem = calloc(mem_size, 1);
exit_if_true(mem == NULL, "calloc()");
```

I notice in passing that `return 1;` is quite natural and correct and POSIX-compliant — it's a really good idea to specify exactly what integral value your process returns on error — but *technically* it's not "ANSI C" to do that. ANSI C wants you to use `return EXIT_FAILURE;`, which returns an implementation-defined "failure" result.

More importantly, you accidentally swapped the arguments to `calloc`. [They go `nmemb, size`.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) And yes, I had to look it up. I know that I *always* have to look it up. This, IMVHO, is a reason never to use `calloc` — I'd use `malloc` and then do an explicit `memset` if for some reason I *needed* zero-initialization.

Notice that `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

---

```
long spc = 0, ipc = 0;
```

Again, I strongly recommend one declaration per line.

What's weird here is that you're carefully defining these variables as `long`... but then casting them to `size_t` everywhere they're used! Why not just define them as `size_t`?

I also personally dislike seeing `long` because its size varies from platform to platform. "Everyone knows" that on common desktop systems `int` is 32 bits and `long long` is 64, but the size of `long` might be one or the other, depending on architecture and operating system. Using `long` is like saying, "I *want* to have portability problems a year from now."

---

```
free(mem);
```

This is a double-free and crash bug. `bf_interp` will have freed the *original* value of `mem` the very first time it does a `realloc`. Either

- pass `mem` by address to `bf_interp` so that `bf_interp` can modify it, or
- transfer the responsibility for freeing `mem` into `bf_interp` — turn `bf_interp` into a "sink."

Since `bf_interp` uses `mem` as scratch space, trashing its semantic *contents* as well as its physical pointer value, I think the second option above makes quite a bit of sense.

The one thing that might change my mind is if you could demonstrate that `bf_interp` does not "trash" `mem`'s contents, but rather updates them in a meaningful way. For example, if `bf_interp` took a parameter `num_steps`, and ran the program for that many steps, and then returned, so that you could "resume" the interpretation later — well, then it would make sense that `bf_interp` needs a way to pass `mem` back out to its caller. (But then `bf_interp` would also need a way to pass the rest of its state — `ipc` and `spc`. And now you're halfway to inventing object-oriented programming.)

---

Oh hey — your entire use of `realloc` is wrong!

```
                tmp = realloc(sp, sp_size + DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                exit_if_true(tmp == NULL, "realloc()");

                memset(tmp+sp_size, 0, DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                memcpy(tmp, sp, sp_size);

                sp_size += DEF_MEM_SIZE;

                free(sp);
                sp = tmp;
```

This should be simply

```
                sp = realloc(sp, sp_size + DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                exit_if_true(sp == NULL, "realloc()");

                memset(sp + sp_size, 0, DEF_MEM_SIZE);
                sp_size += DEF_MEM_SIZE;
```

Your version would become correct (but still inefficient) if you replaced `realloc` with simply `malloc`. The point of `realloc` is that it does the *re*-allocation for you; you don't have to manually free the old buffer or copy over the data.

If you used something like `gcov` to look at your code coverage, you'd see that your test cases (you have test cases, right?) never hit this codepath. That's why you didn't find the bug. If you had hit this codepath, the program definitely would have crashed.

---

```
    /* I would put this inside the switch
     * but clang warns about "unreachable code".
     */
    int nest;
```

The declaration of this variable should go at the variable's point of use. Like this:

```
                for (int nest = 1; nest != 0; )
```

---

Your usage message says:

```
Usage: ./a.out [file] (args...)
```

This isn't right, is it? I mean, `file` is not optional, and there is no such thing as `args...`.

Comment: Your point about defining the variables after the `if` is invalid. Note the title, which says "in ANSI C".

Comment: Same for the inline functions.

Comment: Nice note about the `calloc`, but the order of the arguments doesn't matter. It's really just a simple multiplication and a check for overflow.

Comment: `spc` and `ipc` can't be `size_t` because then the checks for `< 0` on them wouldn't work.

Comment: About `realloc` and the double free -- extremely good catch. I wrote this at 9:00 last Friday, so I guess that's why.

Comment: I wish I had test cases but they'd be 32KB long to test this. Sadly, `gcov` doesn't work well for me. I tried it once but it just didn't work.

Comment: I can't have the declaration of `nest` inside the `for` loop because would not be ANSI C.

Comment: I'll fix the usage, though.

Comment: @JL2210: As far as I know, ANSI C tracks ISO C, so the current standard is 2018. Admittedly my close knowledge of C stops circa 1999 (20 years ago), but if you're saying that you can't use `inline` functions because you're stuck on 19*89* (30 years ago)... *and* without GNU C extensions... well, I don't think you have any valid engineering reason for that.

Comment: You can definitely test the `spc`-realloc bug with a short test case. Use nested loops.

Comment: I completely forgot about the current version of ANSI C. I was referring to ANSI C89. I'll clarify that in the title.

Comment: I was mainly concerned with Windows-compatibility.

Comment: Any note on how to make the nesting faster?

Comment: If you're asking whether Windows (MSVC) supports `for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)`, the answer is "yes, since sometime in the '90s."

Comment: Could you please go over performance in this answer?